# How to scroll down to the bottom of page with vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to implement an application composed of several card views and a succeeding button. On each click of the button, the page should be scrolled to its bottom.

I found some Q&As which implement the scrolling by native javascript, but I did not get how to implement it on `Vuetify` framework. I looked at the documentation (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/directives/scrolling) and noticed that the scrolling is to be implemented via `$vuetify.goTo`.

But I did not find the exact way to specify *the bottom* of the page on `Vuetify`-like style.

Is there any good idea to implement it with good `Vuetify` maner?

Answer (score 4):

You can have a computed property returning the height of the page:

```
computed: {
    pageHeight () {
      return document.body.scrollHeight
    }
}
```

And then use vuetify for scrolling to the bottom like:

`$vuetify.goTo(pageHeight)`

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I tried it, and it sometimes worked for me, although I have to deal the order of rendering and `$vuetify.goTo()`.

Comment: What do you mean the order of rendering ?